# How to display multiple returned values in suggestion in twitter typeahead/bloodhound?

Tags: javascript, json, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

Im trying to use [bloodhound](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md) and [typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) to create an autocomplete. The data is being returned correctly but displayed in the options as `undefined` [image: undefined suggestions] 
My code is:

Html:

```
<form class="typeahead" role="search">
       <div class="form-group">
            <input type="search" name="q" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
       </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
                remote: {
                    url: '{{ route('search') }}?query=%QUERY',
                    wildcard: '%QUERY'
                },
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('name'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
            });

            $(".search-input").typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1
            }, {
                source: engine.ttAdapter(),

                // This will be appended to "tt-dataset-" to form the class name of the suggestion menu.
                name: 'profileList',

                // the key from the array we want to display (name,slug...)
                templates: {
                    empty: [
                        '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown"><div class="list-group-item">Nothing found.</div></div>'
                    ],
                    header: [
                        '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown">'
                    ],
                    suggestion: function (data) {
                        var profile = [];
                        profile.push(data);
                        console.log(profile);

                        return '<a href="' + data.slug + '" class="list-group-item">' + data.name + '</a>'
                    }
                }
            });
```

When I `console.log(data)` I get 2 results which look like this:

```
Hello Molly
hello-molly-436057803095647
```

but the values are displayed as `undefined`. The data returned from the backend looks like:

```
{"name":"Hello Molly","slug":"hello-molly-436057803095647"}
```

I want to display `name` and `slug` like this: `return '<a href="' + data.slug + '" class="list-group-item">' + data.name + '</a>'` as a suggestion. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that gets stuck I had to create a transform function:

```
transform: function(response) {
                    return $.map(response, function (profile) {
                        return {
                            name: profile.name,
                            slug: profile.slug
                        }
                    });
                },
```

to map out the json response. Also if your using a lot of browser caching clear your cache as this can stop the javascript from updating.

Full code:

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
                remote: {
                    url: '{{ route('search') }}?query=%QUERY',
                    wildcard: '%QUERY',
                    transform: function(response) {
                        return $.map(response, function (profile) {
                            return {
                                name: profile.name,
                                slug: profile.slug
                            }
                        });
                    },
                },
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('name', 'slug'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace

            });

            engine.initialize();

            $(".search-input").typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1,
                displayKey: 'name',
            }, {
                source: engine.ttAdapter(),

                // This will be appended to "tt-dataset-" to form the class name of the suggestion menu.
                name: 'profileList',

                // the key from the array we want to display (name,id,email,etc...)
                templates: {
                    empty: [
                        '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown"><div class="list-group-item">Nothing found.</div></div>'
                    ],
                    header: [
                        '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown">'
                    ],
                    suggestion: function (data) {
                        return '<a href="' + data.slug + '" class="list-group-item">' + data.name + '</a>'
                    }
                }
            });
```